# Use of ADD/SUB instructions in SICXE

Tags: assembly

Currently learning about SIC/XE, and I understand that there are instructions for adding and subtracting, alongside LDA. But how come we can't simply use +/-?

Basically I'm trying to find the difference between

```
LDA    ALPHA - BETA
```

and

```
LDA    ALPHA
SUB    BETA
```

Comment: `LDA` takes a single parameter, the address of the memory location to load from. `LDA ALPHA-BETA` would instruct the *assembler* to subtract those two addresses (NOT the variables at those addresses), and use the result as the address to load from - it's not likely to be a useful address!  Each assembly instruction does a fixed amount of work and takes a specific number of bits in memory - they cannot have arbitrarily complicated expressions stuffed into them.

Comment: @jasonharper that makes perfect sense, thank you!

Comment: Assembly is text-mapping or "mnemonics" of the HW capabilities of the CPU. If the CPU does for example execute addition of accumulator and memory at address x when it hits two byte opcode "1 x", then that's what you have in Assembly as "add x", you can't encode "x+z*13-44", if there's no such encoding designed in the CPU HW. There are some assemblers supporting compile-time expressions, but then the result must fit the HW instruction variant, and some platforms+assemblers support "pseudo instructions" which compile into 2-3 native ones, but if you need more abstraction, you shouldn't use asm.